File drag drop HTML/Typescript stops my SPA development server (exit code -1)
I have an Microsoft Visual Studio Angular/Typescript project with an ASP.NET core backend that the typescript can load data from with http Gets.  The backend starts up correctly:
info: IqTest.ApplicationPartsLogger[0]
      Found the following application parts: 'IqTest, IqTest, IqTest, IqTest' with the following controllers: 'AuthController, HomeController, IQTestController'
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:7109
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5109
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\CodeProjects\IQTest2\IqTest\IqTest\
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager[0]
      No SPA development server running at https://localhost:44436 found.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyMiddleware[0]
      SPA proxy is not ready. Returning temporary landing page.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyMiddleware[0]
      SPA proxy is ready. Redirecting to https://localhost:44436.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager[0]
      SPA development server running at 'https://localhost:44436'

And the web page loads until I click on the file dialog selector, for which the HTML is:
<div>
  <div class="dropzone" fileDragDrop (filesChangeEmiter)="onFileChangeE($event)">
    <div class="text-wrapper">
      <div class="centered">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" multiple>
        <label for="file"><span class="textLink">Select your file</span> or Drop it here!</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

and the typescript .ts file is:
  onFileChange(event: Event) 
  {
    if (event != null && (<HTMLInputElement> event.target) != null && (<HTMLInputElement>event!.target).files != null)
    {
      if ((<HTMLInputElement>event!.target).files!.length)
      {
        this.file = (<HTMLInputElement>event!.target).files as FileList;
      }
    }
    
    this._snackBar.open("Successfully upload!", 'Close', {
      duration: 2000,
    });
  }

As soon as I choose the select file button in the browser, the SPA server exits:
...
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager[0]
SPA development server running at 'https://localhost:44436'
C:\CodeProjects\IQTest2\IqTest\IqTest\bin\Debug\net6.0\IqTest.exe (process 34360) exited with code -1.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
If I remove the code:
 this._snackBar.open("Successfully upload!", 'Close', {
      duration: 2000,
    });

then this doesn't happen.
The _snackbar is added with dependency injection in the constructor:
constructor( private http: HttpClient, private accountService: AccountService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string,
               private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
               private _snackBar: MatSnackBar, public dialog: MatDialog
             )
  {
    this.httpClient = http;
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    let userName: string | null = localStorage.getItem('user');
  }

In the browser, the snackBar dialog shows correctly, but somehow this causes the backend to exit.  At this point the web page keeps working until it tries to do any web calls to the ASP.Net Core backend, which is no longer running, giving the message in the browser console that the target machine actively refused the connection to it.
How can I investigate this further?
